# Error con geolocalizacion en android studio Unable to get provider

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, geolocalización

Esta es mi clase `MapsActivity`:

```
package com.example.em645.prueba;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    private double latitud = 0.0, longitud = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        miUbicacion();
    }

    private void agregarMarcador(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);

        if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();
            marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coordenadas)
                    .title("Mi posicion actual")
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));
            mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
        }

        private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                latitud = location.getLatitude();
                longitud = location.getLongitude();
                agregarMarcador(latitud, longitud);
            }
        }

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                actualizarUbicacion(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        private void miUbicacion() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            actualizarUbicacion(location);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

y al arrancar la app se cae y me da el siguiente error:

```
12-05 12:05:12.372 32315-32315/com.example.em645.prueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.em645.prueba, PID: 32315
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.em645.prueba-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.em645.prueba-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4810)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4402)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.em645.prueba-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.em645.prueba-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4795)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4402)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4342) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero al parecer el error es con Firebase no con Location, ¿Estas usando Firabase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"

Puedes realizar un downgrade a :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

ya que al parecer las versones 9.2 a  9.4 no contienen la clase `FirebaseInitProvider`

Pero te sugieron puedes actualizar Google play services auna revisión mayor que la 30 :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado cambiando en el grandle
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
por 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'